# Uso de if e else

Tags: r

Estou com um problema e não consigo resolver. 
Estou criando uma função e em determinado momento uso *if*s e *else*. 
No argumento x da função : develop <- function(x, temp, data) eu deixarei a opção para o usuário colocar 5 strings. Então eu fiz os *if* e *else* para caso colocar uma, a função vai fazer determinada coisa e assim por diante. 
Meu problema é que só está funcionando na primeira opção de string que coloco. Nas outras diz que o objeto não foi encontrado.

```
calb <- "calb"
if (x == calb & temp == 25){
  cat("O valor de p é:", tabela.calb25[[1]]$"Pr(>F)"[1]) 
  x11()
  boxplot(Peso ~ Idade + Substrato , data = dados.calb25) 
} else if (x == calb & temp == 30){ 
  cat("O valor de p é:", tabela.calb30[[1]]$"Pr(>F)"[1]) 
  x11() 
  boxplot(Peso ~ Idade + Substrato , data = dados.calb30) 
} else if (x == calb & temp == 35){
  cat("O valor de p é:", tabela.calb35[[1]]$"Pr(>F)"[1]) 
  x11() 
  boxplot(Peso ~ Idade + Substrato , data = dados.calb35) 
}else if (x == cmeg & temp == 25){ 
  cat("O valor de p é:", tabela.cmeg25[[1]]$"Pr(>F)"[1]) 
  x11()
  boxplot(Peso ~ Idade + Substrato , data = dados.cmeg25)
```

E assim vai até eu terminar as 5 opções. Nesse caso funciona a primeira (calb) e por exemplo, a cmeg já da que o objeto não foi encontrado. Eu já tentei colocar o `x == "cmeg"` porém sem sucesso.

Alguém pode me ajudar ?

Comment: Esse exemplo não é reprodutível.

Comment: @NoobSaibot Eu tive cuidado, o código faz exatamente o mesmo que o anterior. O problema do AP é na variável `cmeg`, não nos `x11/boxplot`. Creio que é melhor simplificar para podermos nos concentrar no problema e não em código confuso. Mas tudo bem, não há problema.

Comment: @NoobSaibot OK, vou responder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Em primeiro lugar, como é dito nos comentários, o código não é reprodutível. Por dois motivos: 1) não temos dados para testar soluções; 2) na pergunta é dito que se trata de uma função mas não sabemos como é chamada.

Eu começaria por simplificar o código usando o seguinte:

```
calb <- "calb"
if (x == calb) {
    if (temp == 25) {
        cat("O valor de p é:", tabela.calb25[[1]]$"Pr(>F)"[1], "\n")
        dados <- dados.calb25
    } else if (temp == 30) {
        cat("O valor de p é:", tabela.calb30[[1]]$"Pr(>F)"[1], "\n")
        dados <- dados.calb30
    } else if (temp == 35) {
        cat("O valor de p é:", tabela.calb35[[1]]$"Pr(>F)"[1], "\n")
        dados <- dados.calb35
    }
} else {
    if (x == cmeg) 
        if (temp == 25) {
            cat("O valor de p é:", tabela.cmeg25[[1]]$"Pr(>F)"[1], "\n")
            dados <- dados.cmeg25
        }
}

x11()
boxplot(Peso ~ Idade + Substrato, data = dados)
```

Depois, antes dos `if/else`, tentaria ver o valor de `x` com `print(x)`.
Ou talvez qualquer coisa assim:

```
cat("x:", x, "\tcalb:", calb, "\tcmeg:", cmeg, "\n")
```

Esta instrução printa as variáveis em questão todas numa linha, separadas por tabs (`"\t"`). E sem saber os resultados disto, sem saber os valores destas variáveis, é difícil ou mesmo impossível dizer mais.

Comment: Obrigado pelas respostas pessoal. =)

Answer (score 3):

Seu problema está no uso da `{}`, pois acho que o R está tentando compilar tudo depois do primeiro *else* ao mesmo tempo. Para te facilitar a construção da função use `ifelse(test, yes, no)`.
No seu caso ficará algo assim:

```
ifelse(test, yes, 
 ifelse(test, yes, 
  ifelse(test, yes, 
   ifelse(test, yes, 
    ifelse(test, yes, no)))))
```